# Angular4: Error when constructing styles array dynamically

Tags: angular

I am using the latest angular - version 4.
My component has this code:

```
export function getCssUrl(){
  return 'http://localhost/foo/foo.css';
}
@Component({
 selector: 'app-root',
 templateUrl: './app.component.html',
 styles: ['@import "' +getCssUrl()+'"'],
 encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {}
```

When I run ng serve, the style works fine, i.e the getCssUrl function is resolved and the css is loaded correctly. ng build also works fine. But when I run 
    ng build -prod
then i get the error:

```
ERROR in Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Calling function 'getCssUrl', function calls are not supported. Consider replacing the function or lambda with a reference to an exported function, resolving symbol AppComponent
```

Comment: Have you try `styleUrls` ?

Comment: Same problem with styleUrls as well.

Comment: Have you use `styleUrls: [getCssUrl()]` . I think no need for @import in `styleUrls`

Comment: Yes I tried that - it does not work. Gives the same error

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to try the following

styles: [getCssUrl],

Adding getCssUrl without the ()

Comment: What do you think the problem was, and why do you think this would solve it?